# Deleting multiple IDs with MediatR Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Pretty straightforward question. I want to be able to delete multiple IDs, just like the example below.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(List<int> id)`
```

### Snippet

```cs
[HttpDelete("{id:int}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int id)
{
    await Mediator.Send(new DeleteRoomCommand { Id = id }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return NoContent();
}

public class DeleteRoomCommand : IRequest
{
    public long Id { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteRoomCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteRoomCommand>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DeleteRoomCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(DeleteRoomCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entity = await _context.Rooms.FindAsync(request.Id).ConfigureAwait(false);

        if (entity == null)
        {
            throw new NotFoundException(nameof(Room), request.Id);
        }

        _context.Rooms.Remove(entity);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you asking how to write the new command and handler to accept an enumerable? Or how to implement the behavior using the DbContext?

Comment: @AdamG, yes I'm asking on how to achieve that. It should be using same command I guess. I'm not sure how the others are doing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You seem to be asking two questions:

1. How do I write a new command and handler for MediatR that will accept and pass an enumerable of IDs instead of just one?
2. How do I write a DbContext call to handle that enumerable?

The IRequest object is just a simple class that contains the data you need to process it. You can create a new pluralized command class that accepts an enumerable of IDs, and a new handler designed to handle that case. You'll need to tweak this based on your own testing.

```
public class DeleteRoomsCommand : IRequest
{
    public IEnumerable<long> Ids { get; set; }
}

public class DeleteRoomsCommandHandler : IRequestHandler<DeleteRoomsCommand>
{
    private readonly IApplicationDbContext _context;

    public DeleteRoomCommandHandler(IApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public async Task<Unit> Handle(DeleteRoomsCommand request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var entities = await _context.Rooms.Where(r => request.Ids.Contains(r.Id)); // .ConfigureAwait(false);

        _context.Rooms.RemoveRange(entities);

        await _context.SaveChangesAsync(cancellationToken); // .ConfigureAwait(false);

        return Unit.Value;
    }
}
```

Your new call is instantiated the same, taking the IDs received by your controller and assigning them to a new MediatR command:

```
await Mediator.Send(new DeleteRoomsCommand { Ids = ids }); //.ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Your new method could accept the list of IDs via query parameter or via the body, depending on your need or convention.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! ```[HttpDelete]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(DeleteRoomsCommand command)
{
    await Mediator.Send(command).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return NoContent();
}
``` and this would be in the controller?

Comment: You'd probably want to accept the `List<>` from the controller signature and assign it to a new command object, just like your existing code is doing.

Comment: would you like to add it to the answer?

Comment: I can add the mediator call, but it's up to your specific implementation as to how you opt to handle the method signature to receive the IDs (i.e. pass the IDs via query parameter with [FromQuery] or in the body with [FromBody]) and what HTTP response is appropriate (202 vs 204, etc.)

Comment: it doesn't really matter to me.

```[HttpDelete("{ids}")]
public async Task<ActionResult> Delete([FromQuery] IEnumerable<long> ids)
{
    await Mediator.Send(new DeleteLecturersCommand { Ids = ids }).ConfigureAwait(false);

    return NoContent();
}
``` is this good?

Comment: I'm not sure that's something we can answer for you, it depends on your use case, what is communicating with the endpoint, and the volume of data. You can do [HttpDelete] (since the ID is no longer part of the route) and either receive the data from the query parameters or the body, whichever works best for you, they're both acceptable.